# How does env command really work

Tags: linux, shell, environment-variables

I'm new using environment variables and i'm testing how to pass and override environment vars to my scripts.

To test its behaviour, i've created a simple trivial script named `testenv.sh` as follow:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo $COLOR
```

So, when i run

```bsh
$ env COLOR=RED ./testenv.sh
```

I get the expected stdout `RED`.

---

However my question is, why if i run the following command

```bsh
$ env COLOR=RED echo $COLOR
```

I don't get the same result as above, in fact is a blank stdout.

Comment: similar: [How do I set an environment variable on the command line and have it appear in commands?](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/56444)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$COLOR` is expanded by the shell before `env` calls `/bin/echo`.

This cannot work unless you let `env` call a shell script that expands the variable.

Even:

```
COLOR=RED echo $COLOR
```

does not work as you expect since Shell Variables are expanded before the new environment is set up.

You need to split this into two lines:

```
COLOR=RED
echo $COLOR
```

to make it work as you expect.

If you call:

```
env COLOR=RED sh -c 'echo $COLOR'
```

it works because the single quotes prevent variable expansion and the variable expansion is delayed for the time when the new shell is run with the new environment.

Comment: @schily it didn't work yet, the echo still prints a blank stdout because env vars are ephemerals

Comment: The answer written by @roaima really works.

Comment: @Juan-Kabbali You did not read my answer. Before the last edit, I did not post any working example based on `env`.

Comment: yeah ! so the functional example was using `shell vars` and not `env`. It works !